# How to prevent spaces in compiled SASS with / divisor syntax

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to achieve the following output via SASS (***without*** spaces):

```
-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1;
```

My issue is SASS outputs this (***with*** spaces):

```
-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1;
```

---

Investigating a lil further...

According to the SASS documentation it is possible to output compiled CSS with a `/` divisor symbol

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division-and-slash

They show some examples like this...

```
p {
  font: 10px/8px;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
p {
  font: 10px/8px;
}
```

Because it is technically valid and permitted CSS. Which upon testing is true, it does indeed output the `/` syntax ***without*** the spaces as expected.

It appears certain properties (like `font`) will output without spaces, but other properties (like `-o-min-device-pixel-ratio`) do not.

Is there any way to force or change a setting in SASS to achieve this?

Comment: I wonder how it handles the `/` in `calc` properties, which needs the space on both sides. More generally, unless there's some work-around for the problem you mention, it's as good a reason as any for not using something like SASS that mucks with your CSS.

Comment: Seems to handle the `/` in `calc` properly, preserving the spaces on both sides.

Comment: @torazaburo SASS is amazing, would never consider ditching it. This is a pretty obscure issue I'm sure, and I could always compile SASS with an added plain jane CSS file if absolutely necessary. Good to hear calc() works properly though!

Comment: Did you check to verify that `-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1` works while `-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1` does not?  Because they seem to have the same results to me in Opera:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/xHoay

Comment: @cimmanon it could very well be totally fine to have the spaces for opera's sake.

Comment: If it works then what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @cimmanon curiosity of why the behavior is different in SASS in general and for the case I run into a different property it doesnt work for.

Comment: Curiosity is irrelevant.  If Sass is taking valid CSS and generating invalid CSS, the appropriate place to go is to the maintainers of Sass and submit a but report.  Also, media queries aren't properties.